# Dstream Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Hello I wrote the following code

```
val receivedStream: DStream[PubsubSparkMessage] =
      PubsubSource.createStream(ssc, pubsubConfig, pubsubSubscriber)
    @volatile var receivedMessages: List[PubsubSparkMessage] = List() //scalastyle:ignore
    receivedStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        receivedMessages = List(rdd.collect)
        receivedMessages
      }
    }
```

I am getting an error because type mismatch;
My question is how to modify List[Array[PubsubSparkMessage]] to List[PubsubSparkMessage]

Comment: Please share the error when posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
val list : List[Array[PubsubSparkMessage]] = List()

val result = list.flatMap(x => x)
```